# last record on a gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I'd like to display last record value from a gallery.

Gallery is filtered by dropdown.

Using:

```
Last(Gallery3.AllItems,Quality_score= Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you adding this formula? In which property of what control? Are you getting any error? What is the data/column type of Quality score column?

Comment: Are you facing any problem while using formula in my answer?

Comment: Are you facing any problem while using formula in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Gallery is already filtred in the Items Property, you don't have to apply the filter, just apply the following formula :

```
Last(Gallery3.AllItems)
```

This will return the last record of the gallery, if you want to get a field you apply this :

```
Last(Gallery3.AllItems).FieldName
```

I hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the column value from last record in gallery based on dropdown selection, you can use the formula in below format:

```
Last(Filter(Gallery3.AllItems, Quality_score = Dropdown2_2.Selected.Value)).ColumnName
```

OR

```
Last(Gallery3.AllItems).ColumnName
```